# openssl decryption in javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, cryptography, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am searching for a way to clientside decode RSA respectively openssl encoded messages.

**Idea:**
Special data is only stored encrypted with a public key on the server so that nobody is able to see the real data - even in case of server hacks.
An admin in the adminforce then can "open" these files by transfering them to the browser and some javascript code will decode the data so that it'll never decrypted on the server, only on the secure clientside.
I really need it to be decoded direclty in the browser with custom javascript because these data has then to be used by some algorithms clientside in js.


**Problem:**
There seems to be no openssl library in javascript or i didn't find one yet. While there are several pure js implementation of RSA they only implement the plain RSA algorithm but, plain RSA is not secure to be used as a block cipher and has some attacks like *"choosen plaintext attacks"*.
Does anybody know of an javascript implementation of openssl decoding, or a plugin for firefox/chrome which adds these features to the document? Or any other secure asymetric encryption that's built into javascript?

Comment: There a slight flaw in this approach: if your server is hacked, it's likely that the attacker will also be able to alter the JavaScript it serves, which could transparently send the deciphered content back to the server (and thus to the attacker). Relying on JS implies that the client-side is no longer secure either when this sort of attack occurs. You'd be better off developing a standalone application for this, perhaps a signed Java WebStart (or Applet), so long as it's not signed with a private key held on the server.

Comment: Bruno you're quite right but i don't need an js implementation of openssl running on the webpage which could be compromised by the server. i want to write an extension for an browser which can not be compromised by malicious js-code on a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was pointing out in a comment to your question, the vector of attack you're envisaging (compromised server) implies that the JavaScript is likely to be compromised too, in which case the JavaScript code running on the client shouldn't be trusted anyway. (It would be quite easy to make the JavaScript send the deciphered data back to the server with an asynchronous request in the background: again, since the server would be under the attacker's control, there wouldn't be any need for tricks to circumvent same-origin policies there.)

I would suggest going down the route of a standalone application (such as Java WebStart), perhaps signed (with a private key that's not held on the server).

If you're still willing to go ahead with this sort of architecture, avoid releasing the user's private key into the JavaScript at all cost. This could compromise the user's private key, not just the encrypted data.

When you use a private key in your browser for SSL/TLS client-certificate authentication, the private key isn't exposed to any code used by the server. It's used by the browser for the handshake, and the server gets the certificate (which is public), but the private key doesn't go anywhere near what the HTML+JS code can see. (In fact, in OSX with Safari, the private key is used by the underlying SSL/TLS library, and not even exposed to the user process.)

The JavaScript libraries for RSA that I've seen require direct use of the private key, that is, they need to be able to use the private exponent directly. That's clearly not good if you're in a situation you can't trust the server.

Being able to use a private key within the browser for RSA operations, without letting the script get hold of the private material itself would require tighter integration with the browser, in particular, some API to sign and decipher that would use these functions directly in the browser's security mechanism, without exposing the private key material (overall, a similar approach to what PKCS#11 offers to applications using it).

As far as I'm aware, the current [Mozilla crypto JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto) doesn't provide functions to decipher/sign using the browsers (it's only for certificate request and key generation). There seems to be plans to do this, though:

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Privacy/Features/DOMCryptAPISpec/Latest
- http://mozilla.ddahl.com/domcrypt/demos/demo.html

On the IE plaform, [CAPICOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375732%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) should have been of interest, but it seems to be [deprecated](http://securitymusings.com/article/1922/capicom-is-dead-long-live-um-not-being-able-to-sign-in-the-browser) nowadays.

Comment: An firefox could store the private key secure, even if the webpage got defaced by an attacker. I already stumpled upon the Mozilla Crypto API and sadly it really doesn't support this yet, i hadn't have to ask if it would have been supported :-(

Comment: Indeed. To be honest, I haven't tried DOMCrypt (as mentioned here), but it's also open-source, so it's probably worth investigating: https://github.com/daviddahl/domcrypt.  You'll certainly need to install the plugin, but it doesn't seem to be a bad solution for what you're looking for.

Comment: not the answer i hoped to get but i'll no use my backup plan to build an independent tool installed while there seems to be no good interoperable solution in javascript for a custom firefox plugin

Answer (score 1):

Encrpytion is complex and expensive - particularly assymetric encrpytion (in most cases the assymetric encryption is only used to encrypt a randomly generated symmetric algorithm key).

There are implementations of RSA (and probably other asymmetric algorithms in javascript) and in some cases, compatible implementations in other languages (usually C) - try google for specifics - but I'm not aware of any which handles x509 encryption. OTOH writing a java applet to do this would be trivial.

But why bother? From my understanding of what you've written, you'd get just as much functionality for a lot less effort by using a symmetric algorithm and never sending the key back to the server:

1. allow the user to enter some data in a web page
2. allow the user to enter an encryption key
3. encrypt the data using the key
4. send the encrypted data back to the server
5. provide a decryption page where the user can retrieve the encrypted content and enter the key
6. decrypt the contents

Comment: "... but I'm not aware of any which handles x509 encryption": There's nothing specific about X.509 encryption. If it's an X.509 cert with an RSA key, what matters is the RSA algorithm, not so much the X.509 wrapping (more so, because only the private key is required to decipher, which is independent from way the public key is "packaged": in X.509 cert, PGP cert or plain public key). (Same applies when using an DSA key in the X.509 cert, with DSA.)

Comment: I am aware that asymetric encryption is expensive, but i'll need to encode only a few bytes. Symetric Encryption is no solutions since the server has (temporary) to know the keys, this is a no-go for this purpose. While the "user" is not aware of the encryption, he sends the data to the server without any knowledge of encryption and it's stored there encrypted for the admin to look at the data.

Comment: @Tobias P.: "server has (temporary) to know the keys" - you are thinking that by using lots of sophisticated algorithms you are making the system secure. The only reason the server would need to temporarily know the keys is for transient access to the encrypted content - and you can do that by sending back an unencrypted copy along with the encrypted one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on web server to send you both the encrypted data & the associated JavaScript code to decrypt the data (which could be corrupted in case of a compromised server), you could only download the data from the web server & decrypt it with a standalone application or a webpage with JavaScript that does NOT come from the same webserver (could be from another server or a local file). This way there wouldn't be any responses returned to the originating server or the attacker.

The data kept on the server could be encrypted with a key that only you know about and can decrypt (AES or RSA), and server could only be for storage. For decryption, download data to a trusted local machine first, so you only you will have access to unencrypted data, of course for a very limited amount of time.

Check out this [native implementation of TLS in JavaScript.](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)
Here's a guide to [enable Windows Subsystem for Linux in Win 10](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) to install
Bash, which comes with SSL. [Check your version & get the latest.](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/)

Answer (score -1):

think about this. if there is a server hack, the hacker will have access to your encrypted data and to all your site source code. including the one used to decrypt the data. and it can get those from the website interface in plain javascript by looking at the source of the page.

Comment: It won't get the private key of the end user, though. This still requires action from the legitimate user.

Comment: @TheBrain: What do you mean? Sure, you can implement RSA algorithms in JavaScript, but how does it help the attacker gain access to the private key? For a secure system, the browser should never release the private key to the JS anyway.

Comment: @Bruno: yes you realised the problem, but a firefox plugin - which is coded in js - is not accessible by an attacked web page, so the key could be stored there in a secure manner but even allowing to interact with the encrypted data.

Comment: @TheBrain: i already stumpled upon the stanford library but they do only implement plain RSA which has some weaknesses.

Comment: @Tobias, indeed, if it's a plugin, it's different, it's more similar to a standalone application then (the DOMCrypt API, linked in my answer goes along these lines).